# Flutter: Using animation on a widget with Stateless parent

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-animation

As the title suggests, my widget tree looks something like this:

```
Stateless widget
|
|--Stateful widget
   |
   |--Stateful widget state child with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin
```

I have a button as the part of the `Stateful` widget and I want it to rotate when pressed. I tried using `Transform` widget along with `AnimationController`.
The button does not *seem* to animate upon clicking but after a hot reload, I can see that the button has infact reached it's final state of the animation.

What can be the possible reason behind it and how can I overcome this issue?

**Note:** I'm using `Provider` to manage the state.

Comment: you need `AnimatedBuilder` that builds `Transform` widget

Comment: @pskink ```AnimatedBuilder``` did the job